# Bouncy Castle works differently on Android and Console program. How to encrypt using public key in PEM file

Tags: java, android, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I am encrypting using Bouncy Castle. I am using RSA and public key is stored in PEM file. I am finding that when I run the code in simple console project (not Android project) everything works fine - meaning the encrypted string can be decrypted using the private key. However, when I run the same code in Android app, the encrypted byte array is different for the same public key and is not recognized as valid encryption for the given key pair.

**Details**:
Here is the code that encrypts string using Bouncy Castle and taken out of the console project. This one works fine and produces the encrypted string which is valid encryption for the key pair and can be decrypted.

```
private static void encrypt() {
    try {
        //This example uses the Bouncy Castle library
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        String plainText = "This needs to be encrypted";
        String public_key_file = "PublicKey.pem";

        //Load public key
        PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(new FileReader(public_key_file));
        Object key = parser.readObject();
        parser.close();
        PublicKey pubKey = null;

        if (key instanceof SubjectPublicKeyInfo) {
            SubjectPublicKeyInfo spki = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) key;
            pubKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic
                    (new X509EncodedKeySpec(spki.getEncoded()));
        }

        //Encrypt the plain text
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] encrypted_data = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
        String encoded_data = new String(Base64.encode(encrypted_data));

        System.out.println("Encrypted Value:");
        System.out.println(encoded_data);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Now here is the code taken out of the Android app. The only important difference is that the key file is read from Assets folder. This code also produces encrypted string but it is not valid for the key pair and can't be decrypted.

```
public void encrypt(Context context) {

    try {

        //This example uses the Bouncy Castle library
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

        String plainText = "This needs to be encrypted";
        String public_key_file = "PublicKey.pem";

        //Load public key
        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(public_key_file);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        // read from the input stream reader
        PEMParser parser = new PEMParser(inputStreamReader);

        Object key = parser.readObject();
        parser.close();
        PublicKey pubKey = null;

        if (key instanceof SubjectPublicKeyInfo) {
            SubjectPublicKeyInfo spki = (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) key;
            pubKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic
                    (new X509EncodedKeySpec(spki.getEncoded()));
        }

        //Encrypt the plain text
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pubKey);
        byte[] encrypted_data = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes());
        String encoded_data =
                new String(Base64.encode(encrypted_data));

        Log.d("MyApp", "Encrypted Value:");
        Log.d("MyApp", encoded_data);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.d("MyApp", ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

In both the cases, following things are same:

1. Public Key
2. Actual code written (with difference of reading from Assets folder and logging to Logcat)
3. JDK version (1.7)
4. Bouncy Castle libraries (bcpkix-jdk15on-152.jar and bcprov-jdk15on-152.jar)

What's different: The environment. One is console program and the other is Android App.

**On further investigation while debugging**
I observed that when running the console program the KeyFactory returns instance of "sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl". However when running android app, the KeyFactory returns instance of "com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAPublicKey". Not sure if that's the problem. The encrypted byte array is different for same plain text and public key.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Sandeep

Comment: Could you try with `"RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"` for the `Cipher` instance on both Android and console? If that doesn't work, try `"RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding"` too.

Comment: Note that the ciphertext is supposed to always differ as random information should be used in any secure padding scheme. The difference could be explained by a difference in default padding (Android may not use any for just `"RSA"`).

Comment: @MaartenBodewes has it correct. Don't use defaults unless you know they are reliably platform independent. The transformation string in `Cipher.getInstance(transformation)` should always specify the algorithm, mode, and padding. You are only specifying the algorithm and thus getting the defaults for mode and padding. The Oracle default padding is PKCS1 ver 1.5 but the Bouncycastle default is no padding, hence your problem.

Comment: Thanks many tons Maarten Bodewes!!! After 2-3 days of frustration I finally got it working because of your comment. "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" worked. If you add that as answer I can mark it as so if you would like. Thanks again for helping!!!

Comment: Thank you GregS for elaboration...